# jinja2によるS3ファイルのinclude

Tags: python, html, python3

お世話になっております。

python3のHTMLテンプレートjinja2のinclude機能でS3上にあるファイルをincludeしたいのですが、どのようにすればよいのかわかりません。

```
<div id="sample">
    <!--サンプルHTMLを読み込む-->
    {% include "https://.../sample.html" %}
</div>
```

上記のようにS3上のHTMLファイルのフルパスを指定してもエラーになりました。

理想はメモリ上にS3上のHTMLをダウンロードして、そのデータをjinja2でdivタグの中に埋め込みたいのですが、どうすればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 表示されたエラーメッセージも質問文に含めてもらうと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。質問は後からでも [編集] できますので必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

jinja2のinclude機能を使ってネットワーク上にあるファイルを`include`することはできませんが、そのファイルを取得する関数を書いて`jinja2`に`render`時に渡すことで実現できます。

以下は、サンプルコードです。

```
from jinja2 import Environment, select_autoescape, FileSystemLoader
import urllib.request

def include_from_url(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
        return f.read()

env = Environment(
    loader=FileSystemLoader('.'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml']),
)
template = env.get_template('template.html')
print(template.render(include_from_url=include_from_url))
```

template.html

```
<div id="sample">
    <!--サンプルHTMLを読み込む-->
    {{include_from_url('https://.../sample.html')}}
</div>
```

なお、`flask`で使っている場合は、`Context Processors`が使えます。
ドキュメント http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#context-processors

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def include_from_url(url):
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
            return f.read()
```